# Я нашел код, помогите понять как он работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография

Это программа шифровальщик ты вводишь слово, ключ шифрования, и оно выводит зашифрованное слово, потом введя это зашифрованное слово, и этот же ключ шифрования выведется слово которое вы писали изначально.
Вот код:

```
run = True
while run:
    a = input('Введи слово для шифрования: ')
    key = input('Введи ключ шифрования: ')
    # переводим ключ в число
    keyBin = 0
    for letter in key:
        keyBin += ord(letter)


    # функция шифрования
    def XOR_cipher(a, keyBin):
        encripted = ''
        for letter in a:
            encripted += chr(ord(letter) ^ keyBin)
        return encripted


    x = XOR_cipher(a, keyBin)


    # функция дешифрования
    def XOR_uncipher(x, keyBin):
        uncripted = ''
        for symbol in x:
            uncripted += chr(ord(symbol) ^ keyBin)
        return uncripted


    y = XOR_uncipher(x, keyBin)

    print("Зашифровонное слово:" + x)
    print("Слово которое было изначально:" + y)
    print("<!--------!>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шифрование на основе операций XOR использует свойство:
(a XOR k) XOR k = a
где k – выступает в роли ключа

Ваша программа шифрует посимвольно: т.е. применяет к каждому символу исходной строки операцию XOR. 
Расшифровывает она так же посимвольно, применяя вновь операцию XOR и тот же ключ.